# How to get data using async await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, async-await, next.js

How to get the data correctly

```
import { NextApiHandler } from "next";
import data from "../../../lib/data.json";

const cars: NextApiHandler = (_req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(data);
};

export default cars;
```

I tried to use async await for getting data but something went wrong. When I`m trying to print in console.log what is "cars" it returns me function instead of promise.

Comment: Well, it is a function. And there aren't any promises anywhere near that code you've show us. So I don't know why you would expect anything else.

Comment: @Quentin How to get data from this func? I think we chould pass callback functions when we use cars(). Like this cars(callback1, callback2). Is it correct?

Comment: Well you could pass in objects which match the Request and Response object formats … but why? The function is designed to be used as an HTTP endpoint in Next.js. If you just want to read `data.json` then going through that function is a waste of time.

Comment: I agree it's a waste of time, I just learn next/js and NextApiHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way to get data

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Item from '../Item/Item';


const Items = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
     
    useEffect( ()=>{
     fetch('http://localhost:5000/items') 
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => setItems(data));  
    }, [])
    return (
        <div id='items' className='container'>
            <h1 className='item-title'>Items For You</h1>
            <div className="items-container">
            {
                items.map(item => <Item
                key={item._id}
                item={item}
                >
                </Item>)
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Items;
```